# Incorrect UDP data reception in Matlab

Tags: matlab, networking, udp, fpga

My FPGA is continuously sending UDP packets on network using 10/100/1000 Mbps ethernet and i have written a MATLAB code to capture the data. FPGA kit is connected to a 1 gbps switch and then to PC.

The problem is that after a certain number of packets **(around 1080000 Bytes)** are received in Matlab, the next packets that are received are corrupted although the FPGA is sending correct data which i have verified by running Matlab with Wireshark.

1) Does it have something to do with the fact that the transmission rate from FPGA is high (5.18 Mbps in Wireshark) & the reception rate in Matlab is low?

2) Is it because of some internal memory issue. No more packets are received after around 1080000 Bytes worth of UDP data is received (problem shown in figure)? I tried changing the buffer_size & buffer_read_count but to no avail.

3) Is it because of the Matlab's internal buffer getting FULL? Will flushinput() command be of any help in this case if indeed the buffer is getting FULL?

I am pasting the Matlab code below.

```
clc
clearall
closeall

packet_size = 18;                %Size of 1 Packet
buffer_size = 1000*packet_size; % Buffer to store 1000 packets each of Packet_Size
buffer_read_count  = 100;         %How many times the buffer must be read 

do_post_processing = 1;

u=udp('192.168.0.100','RemotePort',4660,'Localport',4661);

set(u,'DatagramTerminateMode','off');   
set(u, 'InputBufferSize', 3*buffer_size);
set(u,'Timeout', 10); 

fopen(u);

x=tic;

ii=1;
kk = 1;

while(1)
      if(u.BytesAvailable>= buffer_size) 
            [a, count] = fread(u, buffer_size);

            data(:, kk) = a;

            data_buffer_read = reshape(a, packet_size, buffer_size/packet_size);

            data_start(:,kk) = (data_buffer_read(18,1:10)).';   

            data_end(:,kk)   = (data_buffer_read(18,end-10:end)).';   

            kk = kk + 1;

      end

      if(kk == buffer_read_count + 1)
          break;
      end

end

fclose(u);

%delete(u);

t=toc(x);

bw = (buffer_size*buffer_read_count*8)/t;

fprintf('Achieved data rate: %e bps\n', bw);

% post processing

data_reshape = reshape (data, packet_size, buffer_size*buffer_read_count/packet_size);

if(do_post_processing==1)
     plot(data_reshape.');
     title('UDP Data v/s Total Packets at 10 Mbps Ethernet Link');
     xlabel('Total Number of Packets'); 
     ylabel('Packet Data');
end
```

A thread i posted previously provides a link to this problem.

[Slow speed of UDP reception in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237984/slow-speed-of-udp-reception-in-matlab)

[image: Image showing the problem at 10 Mbps]

[image: Image showing the problem at 1000 Mbps]

Please provide any guidance about this issue.

Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: Could you put `disp(u.BytesAvailable)` inside the while loop and see what happens? That may tell you if the buffer is filling up. Also, you should try adding a `pause(0.01)` or `drawnow` inside the while loop to make sure that it is updating the buffer.

Comment: @Trogdor I can confirm that the buffer doesnt fill up as i placed `disp(u.BytesAvailable)` inside the while loop. Once i read the buffer inside the if statement the buffer again starts from a low value say around 30's. Meaning that the buffer is emptied once i start reading it. I have also inserted a pause(0.001) inside the if statement it didnt have much effect just that incorrect packets started little earlier than before around **(997560 bytes)**

Comment: @Trogdor could flush_input help after receiving the 1080000 Bytes of data to remove any data that may be blocking new incoming data. Thanks in advance for providing valuable suggestions.

Comment: @Yvon Please help
!!

Comment: @Trogdor checked flush_input(udp_object) it doesnt serve my purpose.

Comment: This is a tough one, it still sounds to me like matlab is unable to keep up with the rate of data. Could you try changing the data rate? Do you preallocate your memory arrays, data_start, data_end, etc?

Comment: Have tried at Multiple data rates. Slow & High. But still the problem persists. If Matlab was unable to cope with data rate than changing data rate would have had a considerable effect. But it didnt.

Comment: @Trogdor Interestingly once i reduced the FPGA's transmission rate to around 110 kilo bits/s ( in this scenario i generate a packet from FPGA every 8ms), the problem doesn't appear. i have checked by capturing 200,000 packets in Matlab & wireshark. But the problem is present at if i generate a packet every 800us at 1.1 Mega bits/sec)

Comment: @Trogdor any guesses???

Comment: I'm out of ideas. It's possible that Matlab simply can't handle the data rate, but that would surprise me. You might want to consider writing a python script that reads the UDP data and writes it to a file for matlab to read. A hack at best, but it would probably work.

Comment: @Trogdor Why do you say that it surprises you?? Do have any experience of receiving/transmitting data over 1Mbps in Matlab. Secondly, i ve checked writing UDP data from Matlab to FPGA in this case i get around 5 Mbps data speed checked in wireshark. Why is the txn speed not going beyond 100 Kbps. Could i be making some error in the design.

Comment: I've gotten ~10 Mbps using TCPIP, no experience with UDP though.